# Reverse Engineering API's of Browser games

Tags: game-hacking, api, api-hacking, api-reversing

I like the idea of Reverse Engineering API's and creating bots/scripts for Browser games. However, I am a beginner in the Computer Science field. I recently started my Computer Science Degree and would like to know what modules should I look out for that typically covers this sort of thing.

We have a course in second year labelled - 'Full Stack Developing' would that be something I should take?

Comment: Can you share the course offerings from your degree program?

Comment: Browser games are HTTP(S) based. Therefore the best start is to set-up a proxy like mitmproxy, Zap, Fiddler, Chares, redirect your web-browser to the proxy and look at the HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the implementation of the game in the browser.

The API is likely a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API and the format for data exchange is likely [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

A modern full stack web development course will often cover both of these subjects.

In terms of reverse engineering the API itself, there's not a huge challenge. Restful APIs and JSON are chosen because they're easy to use and easy to integrate.